# MySQL, PHP - query is getting all records when datetime is used

Tags: php, mysql

I have query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM messages
WHERE recipients LIKE '%0688427893%'
AND 'dateadded' > '2015-05-13 12:52:57'
ORDER BY dateadded ASC
```

This should select only messages that are added after **2015-05-13 12:52:57**, but instead of doing that, it is selecting all messages. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM messages
WHERE recipients LIKE '%0688427893%'
AND dateadded > '2015-05-13 12:52:57'
ORDER BY dateadded ASC
```

If you want to escape a column name in MySQL then use backticks

```
`dateadded`
```

Using quotes turns it into a normal string

```
'dateadded'
```